# sumproduct with two different tables, multiply last 4 records with another table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table A & B, Need to multiply from current row to last 4 days value, with corresponding 4 rows of another table.

Table A

| date | values | seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-07-2022 | 40 | 4 |
| 01-07-2022 | 90 | 3 |
| 01-07-2022 | 20 | 2 |
| 01-07-2022 | 80 | 1 |
| 02-07-2022 | 30 | 4 |
| 02-07-2022 | 10 | 3 |
| 02-07-2022 | 60 | 2 |
| 02-07-2022 | 20 | 1 |
| 03-07-2022 | 70 | 4 |
| 03-07-2022 | 50 | 3 |
| 03-07-2022 | 10 | 2 |
| 03-07-2022 | 80 | 1 |

Table B

| date | values |
| --- | --- |
| 29-06-2022 | 20 |
| 30-06-2022 | 21 |
| 01-07-2022 | 22 |
| 02-07-2022 | 23 |
| 03-07-2022 | 24 |

How to sum the table A & B:
summation for 02-07-2022

| table B |  | table A |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date | value | date | values | (A.value * B.value) | sum(I) |
| -------- | --------- | ---------- | --------- | --------------------- | ------- |
| 29-06-2022 | 20 | 02-07-2022 | 30 | 600 |  |
| 30-06-2022 | 21 | 02-07-2022 | 10 | 210 |  |
| 01-07-2022 | 22 | 02-07-2022 | 60 | 1320 |  |
| 02-07-2022 | 23 | 02-07-2022 | 20 | 460 | 2590 |

summation for 03-07-2022

| table B |  | table A |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date | value | date | values | (A.value * B.value) | sum(I) |
| -------- | --------- | ---------- | --------- | --------------------- | ------- |
| 30-06-2022 | 21 | 03-07-2022 | 70 | 1470 |  |
| 01-07-2022 | 22 | 03-07-2022 | 50 | 1100 |  |
| 02-07-2022 | 23 | 03-07-2022 | 10 | 230 |  |
| 03-07-2022 | 24 | 03-07-2022 | 80 | 1920 | 4720 |

Expected Output:

| date | values | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29-06-2022 | 20 | null |
| 30-06-2022 | 21 | null |
| 01-07-2022 | 22 | null |
| 02-07-2022 | 23 | 2590 |
| 03-07-2022 | 24 | 4720 |

Answer (score 0):

So the logic was rather poorly described. Thank goodness you examples captured enough detail.

```
select
    b.date
    ,b.value
    ,t.sum
from table_b as b
left join (
select 
    a.date
    ,sum(a.value * b.value) as sum
from table_a as a
join table_b as b 
    on a.date = dateadd(day, a.seq-1, b.date)
group by 1
having count(*) = 4
) as t
    on b.date = t.date
order by 1;
```

gives:

| DATE | VALUE | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-29 | 20 | null |
| 2022-06-30 | 21 | null |
| 2022-07-01 | 22 | null |
| 2022-07-02 | 23 | 2,590 |
| 2022-07-03 | 24 | 4,720 |